# ICanHaz/Mustache.js not rendering template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a mustache.js template defined like so:

```
<script id="wishlist_template" type="text/html">
      <h1>aaa{{ title }}</h1>
    </script>
```

I've tried to use Mustache directly, then ICanHaz.js, neither seem to be doing the job. If I pass in:

```
console.log( ich.wishlist_template('{title: "blah blah"}') );
```

All I see in the console log is:

```
<h1>aaa</h1>
```

I've also tried it with a true object, the one I'm trying to render (the above code is my attempt at figuring out the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'{title: "blah blah"}'` is not a valid object literal, but rather just a string. Instead it should be `{title: "blah blah"}` without the quotes. See the article [A Survey of the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html) for a great explanation of object literals.

Answer (score 0):

remove the spaces around `title` like this: `{{title}}`

spaces are significant there, and Mustache is probably looking for `" title "` inside of your data object instead of `"title"`.

Comment: No dice. I've tried it both ways with the same results unfortunately.

Comment: oh shoot! you are not passing an object, you are passing a string. remove the single quotes from the param in the ich call.